# Cross-thread operation in DataReceived CallBack

Tags: multithreading, visual-c#-express-2010

I have a form with some tabs, in Visual C#

This form is reading a serial port using the callback "serialPort1_DataReceived"

In one of the tabs there is a textBox called textBox_CN2

When the serial is runing and I click on this tab, I have a error when the form try to change the text in textbox

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox_CN2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

         buffer_in[count] = (char)serialPort1.ReadByte();
         count++;

         if (count > 10 && buffer_in[count - 1] == '#' && buffer_in[count - 2] == '@')
            {
               this.textBox_CN2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", buffer_in[2]);
            }

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to update the UI like this:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char[] buffer_in;

        buffer_in[count] = (char)serialPort1.ReadByte();
        count++;

        if (count > 10 && buffer_in[count - 1] == '#' && buffer_in[count - 2] == '@')
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.textBox_CN2.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", buffer_in[2]);
            });
        }

    }
```